# to get the count of multi valued field in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

In solr i have a multiValued field called animal and it has the values {cat,dog} is it possible to get the number of values inside the  multiValued  field in solr(in my example 2)?

Comment: directly, you can't. you could still facet over that field and sum up the facet counts, somehow.

Comment: yup. For that you have to query that individual document, so that it will provide you the exact facet count for that document only.

Comment: is there any way to do this via apache luke?

Comment: luke just gives you the inside of the index. You can look and still have to count it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to count the items in a multivalued field use [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html)

Comment: I think I need to create additional field for storing count alone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get the count of items in a multivalued field.
You can always maintain the field count during indexing and use it.

If not using during query time, you can always count the list size.