# Solr4/Lucene - Get count of the values in MultiValued field?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I'm using solr 4.5, and I have a MultiValued field
and I need to get the number of values of the MultiValued field where I find my keywords?

This is an example:
query: "solr"
id_doc:{1} field_multivalued:{"solr solr","lucene","search"}

I need to get 1 for my document.

Is it possible? Please, any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you need to get which instance of the multivalued field(s) the query matches in?

Comment: yes I need the count of the instance of the multivalued field the query matches in

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13838235/949273  might help.